# Access target domain (hostname) in verify callback

Tags: c, openssl

With OpenSSL 0.9.8 I have set a callback using the SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback
function. However in the callback how can I get access to the target domain of the
OpenSSL connection so I can match the target domain with the certificate domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arg` value that you pass to `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback()` will be passed to your callback function when it is called.  You can use this to pass a pointer to some data structure that contains the domain.